# How remove copyright in minified CSS (with SASS and Rails)?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, comments

I want remove all comment automatically added in my minified CSS assets, using rails and SASS. Example:

```
/*!
 * jQuery UI CSS Framework 1.10.4
 * http://jqueryui.com
 *
 * Copyright 2014 jQuery Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license.
 * http://jquery.org/license
```

I tried:

```
config.sass.line_comments = false # in production config
rake assets:clobber assets:precompile #force recompilation
```

For JavaScript we can do:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(copyright: false)
```

There is an equivalent like:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = Sass.new(copyright: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

you simply dont remove copyrights. there is a reason you have the license and copyright in a minified version.

Comment: Please be impartial. I do not ask a value judgment, good or bad, your answer absolutely not answer the question.

Comment: q: how to remove copyrights. a: dont do it. I think this answer is perfectly fine and protects you from copyright issues in the future.

Comment: I don't think that license information should be in minified version. It's pointless. License information should be stored in some separated "LICENSES.txt" file.